# Ability to sort order jssor thumbnails

Tags: jssor

I am using the http://www.jssor.com/ image gallery without jquery

I am finding even though I've sequentially numbered each image in the directory ie; 01.jpg, 02.jpg etc.. and the same for thumbnails ie 01_tn.jpg, 02_tn.jpg etc.. it seems to be picking up the images in some random order.

My desire is the images number dictate what order the thumbnails are put in.

Is there a solution to sorting the thumnails ?  I am using the http://www.jssor.com/demos/image-gallery-with-vertical-thumbnail.html

What sayeth the group ?

Jay
CompuMatter

Answer (score 0):

Thumbnails are in in the same order as slides. And thumbnails are in a loop.

If you set $Loop to 0 for $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions, you will see the order clearly.

Comment: Tried $loop=0 but still it ignored the numbered filenames as a natural sort order.

How can I get it to sort on the filenames.  I guess that's the main request.

Thanks.

Jay